# GridFS pipe readable stream and return _id of streamed document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am trying to get back the `_id` of a document that has been streamed to MongoDB via GridFS. Is there a way to do this?

The code is very simple. I am running the following to insert the document into MongoDB:

```
readableStream.pipe(bucket.openUploadStream('myFile.pdf');
```

Looking for a way to get the _id back from this stream - if anyone knows a way to do this please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We can listen to the `finish` event of bucket upload stream

```
const uploadStream = bucket.openUploadStream('myFile.pdf');

uploadStream.on("finish", (file) => {
  console.log(file); // data here
});

readableStream.pipe(uploadStream);
```